# Laravel and VueJs pagination not showing all records properly

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent, vuejs2

I added pagination to my code but I just noticed that not all posts are being shown and the pagination is not working properly.

```php
<template>
    <nav id="page_nav" class="pagination is-centered is-rounded" role="navigation" aria-label="pagination">
        <li><a class="pagination-previous" @click.prevent="changePage(1)" :disabled="pagination.current_page <= 1">«</a></li>
        <li><a class="pagination-previous" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page - 1)" :disabled="pagination.current_page <= 1"><</a></li>
        <ul class="pagination-list">
            <li v-for="page in pages">
                <a class="pagination-link" :class="isCurrentPage(page) ? 'is-current' : ''" @click.prevent="changePage(page)">{{ page }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li><a class="pagination-next" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page + 1)" :disabled="pagination.current_page >= pagination.last_page">></a></li>
        <li><a class="pagination-next" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.last_page)" :disabled="pagination.current_page >= pagination.last_page">»</a></li>

    </nav>
</template>

<style>
    .pagination {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['pagination', 'offset'],
        methods: {
            isCurrentPage(page) {
                return this.pagination.current_page === page;
            },
            changePage(page) {
                if (page > this.pagination.last_page) {
                    page = this.pagination.last_page;
                }
                this.pagination.current_page = page;
                this.$emit('paginate');
            }
        },
        computed: {
            pages() {
                let pages = [];
                let from = this.pagination.current_page - Math.floor(this.offset / 2);
                if (from < 1) {
                    from = 1;
                }
                let to = from + this.offset - 1;
                if (to > this.pagination.last_page) {
                    to = this.pagination.last_page;
                }
                while (from <= to) {
                    pages.push(from);
                    from++;
                }
                return pages;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the posts component I have this:

```php
<pagination v-if="pagination.last_page > 1" :pagination="pagination" :offset="5" @paginate="showPosts()"></pagination>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Owner</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(post, id) in posts">
           <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
           <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
           <td>{{ post.description | snippet }}</td>
           <td>{{ post.category.name }}</td>
           <td>{{ post.user.name }}</td>
           <td><button @click.prevent="iniUpdate(id)" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</button></td>
           <td><button @click="deletePost(id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<pagination v-if="pagination.last_page > 1" :pagination="pagination" :offset="5" @paginate="showPosts()"></pagination>
```

The show posts methos looks like this:

```php
showPosts(){
    axios.get('/api/posts?page=' + this.pagination.current_page)
    .then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data.data.data;
        this.pagination = response.data.pagination;
    });              
}
```

Im my controller this is what I use to show the posts:

```php
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::with('user', 'category')->paginate(8);

    $response = [
        'pagination' => [
            'total' => $posts->total(),
            'per_page' => $posts->perPage(),
            'current_page' => $posts->currentPage(),
            'last_page' => $posts->lastPage(),
            'from' => $posts->firstItem(),
            'to' => $posts->lastItem()
        ],
        'data' => $posts
    ];
    return response()->json($response);
}
```

The problem I see is: every time I click on the arrow to see the last page, or on the button with the number of the last page, the rest of the buttons stop showing the relevant pages.

So if I have 8 buttons: when I click on 2 it will show and so forth, until I click on button 8 then nothing else will show any more.

Note: the buttons will simulate that the records are changing, but the records don't change.

How can I make my pagination work properly?